Unable to correctly read configuration based on environment after using Prisma in NestJS
enter image description here。
After adding PrismaModule in app.module.ts, the environment configuration port read in main.ts is incorrect, but the value of process.env.NODE_ENV is correct.
I have consulted the documentation, but I didn't find the answer. I hope that after introducing PrismaModule, I can also read the correct configuration according to the environment.

Try importing the ConfigModule inside your PrismaModule.forRootAsync({ ... }
(above your inject: [ConfigService]) like so: imports: [ConfigModule]
